# Super admin access to a forgotten WP instance?

Tags: multisite, wp-admin

I have inherited a Wordpress instance backed by a MySQL database, hosted on a bare bones server. I have SSH access to the server, and I can even log in with an old set of credentials to the admin panel. But the login I have does not allow me to install plugins, which I now must do.

Given I have the keys to the kingdom, but no knowledge, how can I either find the login for the old super admin or convert the user I can log in as into a super admin?

I'm comfortable with raw SQL, I'm just not familiar with Wordpress at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Super Admins only have meaning in WordPress Multisite. I've assumed below that you're running Multisite, though your question isn't tagged as such.

Super Admins are stored as a [serialized](https://www.php.net/serialize) array in the `{$prefix}_sitemeta` table in the `site_admins` record. In my local installation, with only the user ID `adminpj` as a Super Admin, here's what I see:

```
mysql> SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_sitemeta WHERE meta_key='site_admins';
+-------------+--------------------------+
| meta_key    | meta_value               |
+-------------+--------------------------+
| site_admins | a:1:{i:0;s:7:"adminpj";} |
+-------------+--------------------------+
```

Unserializing the `meta_value`, I get:

```
Array (
    [0] => adminpj
)
```

So you can either a) see what your existing Super Admins are, or b) add your own username to the `site_admins` record.

Comment: Thanks, but I need even more basic info. Where can I find the database connection info?

Comment: That should be in a file named `wp-config.php` in the site's root directory.

Comment: I see it, thanks! I see a db name, username, password, host... I don't see a port. Does that mean it's the default 3306 MySQL port?

Comment: Yes, if the port's unspecified it'll be the default.